# code blocks are not supported in this context in asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I'm creating one html table. I want to hide the table row. I'm putting the attributes `runat=server` and `id` for the particular row, but the row has client side code in it similar to the following code.

```
<% if ((strFlag=="d") || (strApprvdFlag=="y")) {%>
```

After call this line, I got this error.

> Code blocks are not supported in this context in asp.net control.

Below is my sample code:

```
<table>
  <tr colspan="4" ID="trMedical"  scriptrunat="server">
    <td style="WIDTH: 45px;HEIGHT: 12px" align="left" class="LabelTaxText" width="45"><b>G&nbsp;
        </b>
    </td>
    <td style="WIDTH: 182px;HEIGHT: 12px" class="LabelTaxText" align="left" width="182"
        colSpan="2">Medical
    </td>
    <td style="WIDTH: 81px; HEIGHT: 12px" align="right" class="LabelTaxText" width="81">
        <asp:textbox onchange="onChangeFlag(),intOnly(this);" onkeyup="intOnly(this);" onkeypress="return CheckNumericWithOutDecimals(event)"
            id="TxtMedical" tabIndex="24" runat="server" Width="96px" MaxLength="12" style="Z-INDEX: 0"></asp:textbox>
    </td>
    <% if ((strFlag=="d") || (strApprvdFlag=="y")) {%>
        <td class="LabelTaxText" style="WIDTH: 107px; HEIGHT: 12px" align="right" width="107">
            <asp:textbox onchange="onChangeFlag(),intOnly(this);" onkeyup="intOnly(this);" onkeypress="return CheckNumericWithOutDecimals(event)" id="TxtMedicalProof" tabIndex="24"     onblur="charAlert(TxtMedical,TxtMedicalProof)" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="96px">
            </asp:textbox>
        </td>
    <% } %>
    <% if (strApprvdFlag=="y") {%>
        <td class="LabelTaxText" style="WIDTH: 68px; HEIGHT: 24px" align="right" width="68">
            <asp:textbox id="TxtMedicalApproved" tabIndex="24" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="96px"></asp:textbox>
        </td>
        <td class="LabelTaxText" style="WIDTH: 43px">&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="lblMedicalRemarks" Runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    <% } %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 18):

When you add a `runat='server'` to an HTML control you change the rendering and code blocks aren't supported inside. So if there are properties you need to change (style? class?) you probably have to instead of doing this:

```
<tr id='myrow' runat='server'>
    <td> 
        your code here
    </td>
</tr>
```

Do something like this:

```
<tr id='myrow' <%= GetRowProperties() %>>
    <td> 
        your code here
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Note:** `runat='server'` removed from `tr`. Then in your codebehind you can do something like this:

```
protected string GetRowProperties()
{
    return "class='myclass'"; // something like this
}
```

Comment: hi thank you so much..now i got this error Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: Your row CANNOT have runat='server' in it.

Comment: but i need runat server property..then how can i hide the row in code behind..give any idea

Comment: You can wrap it in an <asp:placeholder>

Comment: Why can't you have runat='server' at a row?

Comment: This is not going to work if you have in GetRowProperties a value thats changing like return "id='" + rowId.ToString() + "'";

Answer (score 6):

You can use data binding to control the visibility of a control. That should solve your problem.

```
<tr runat="server">

    some content...

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"
        visible='<%# (strFlag=="d") || (strApprvdFlag=="y") %>'>

        This content will only be rendered if strFlag is "d" or "y"

    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    more content...

</tr>
```

On your OnLoad method, you will need to call the **DataBind()** method to either the PlaceHolder, or any control that contains it, like the tr or even Page:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);

    Page.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: i put the place holder inside the table row... but i got this error System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCellCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell'. 'asp:PlaceHolder' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder'.

Comment: I never tried to use this technique into a <tr runat="server">. Do you really need the TR to be a server-side control?